# Displaying date - three days in long format minus the year in Freemarker

Tags: freemarker

looking for way to display the date in freemarker as "June 1", so long format minus the year. I also need to output the date minus 3 days. So the code that works is

${(.now?long - 259200000)?number_to_date }

but that displays the year as well (June 7, 2021)

**I need to get rid of the year.**

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. For anyone who is reading this in the future:

${(.now?long - 259200000)?number_to_date?string['MMMM dd']}

prints as

Current date, minus 3 days, without year. So for me rn :

**June 7**